# R simulation data with grouped random normal values

Tags: r, tidyverse, simulation

I have a data set with around 10k data points related to products and their prices. I would like to generate simulated sales data from normal distribution that follow specific pattern based on the price of the product. For example if the price is low, e.g., less than 40 sales (quantity) should be extracted from a normal distribution with mean 120 and sd=20. If the price is average, e.g., between 40 and 50, quantity should be extracted from a normal distribution with mean 80 and sd=15. If price is high, e.g., above 50, the quantity should be extracted from a normal with mean 20 and sd=3

I have created the following working example:

```
dt <- tibble(sample(x = c("cheap","mediumA", "mediumB", 
                      "mediumC", "expensive"),
   prob = c(.3, .2,.2,.2, .1), 
   size = 10000,
   replace = TRUE))
dt <- dt %>% 
  mutate(productName=`sample(...)`,
         Price=case_when(
           productName=="cheap"~10,
           productName=="mediumA"~40,
           productName=="mediumB"~45,
           productName=="mediumC"~50,
           TRUE~300)) %>% 
  select(productName, Price)
```

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
dt %>% count(Price)
dt <- dt %>% 
  mutate(
    Quantity=case_when(
  Price<40 ~ 
    rnorm(dt %>%
            filter(Price<40) %>% 
            count(Price) %>% 
            pull(n), 120, 20),
  Price >=40 & Price <= 50 ~ 
    rnorm(dt %>%
            filter(Price >=40 & 
                     Price <= 50) %>% 
            count(Price) %>%
            pull(n) %>% 
            sum(), 80, 15),
  TRUE~ 
    rnorm(dt %>%
            filter(Price>50) %>% 
            count(Price) %>% 
            pull(n), 20, 3)))
```

The above R script produces the following error message:

```
Error: 
Price < 40 ~ rnorm(dt %>% filter(Price < 40) %>% count(Price) %>%      pull(n), 120, 20), 
Price >= 40 & Price <= 50 ~ rnorm(dt %>% filter(Price >= 40 &      
Price <= 50) %>% count(Price) %>% pull(n) %>% sum(), 80,      15), 
TRUE ~ rnorm(dt %>% filter(Price > 50) %>% count(Price) %>% pull(n),      20, 3) 
must be length 1000 or one, not 313, 597, 90 Call rlang::last_error() to see a backtrace
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work would be great.

Comment: can you elaborate on 'it does not work'? are you getting errors? or is it giving the wrong value? If so, could you add that info to the question?

Comment: just for ease of understanding, never add stuff like this to comments. it is useful info for the question and should be added directly to the question

Comment: I have a similar problem using case_when(). I didnt have a problem assigning random variables with rnorm() based on conditions using ifelse(), but when I changed my code to use the case_when(), I get the same error message as the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `ifelse`, however, you need to count how many values are in the range (we do that using `sum`) and generate them together in one go in `rnorm`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
  mutate(Quantity= ifelse(Price < 40, rnorm(sum(Price < 40), 120, 20),
              ifelse(Price <= 50, rnorm(sum(Price >= 40 & Price < 50), 80, 12), 
                                  rnorm(sum(Price > 50), 20, 3))))
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion using case_when instead of ifelse and I still get the same error message. Can you help me understand why it works with ifelse but not with case_when? Thanks.

Comment: @TCS you can return only 1 value from `case_when` in RHS, this `rnorm(sum(Price < 40), 120, 20)` is more than 1 value hence it returns an error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way you can achieve your desired result, using `map` from the `purrr` package which is part of the `tidyverse`:

```
 fun <- function(p) {
   case_when(p < 40 ~ rnorm(1, 120, 20),
             p <= 50 ~ rnorm(1, 80, 15),
             p > 50 ~ rnorm(1, 20, 3))
 }
 
 dt %>%
   mutate(Quantity = map_dbl(Price, fun))
```

Comment: Careful, the first option just recycles the same value. But second option gives desired result